# How to use if else condition for login/logout in php

Tags: php, html

I am working on a e-commerce website. I want a help regarding displaying login & logout but when a user is logged in, user should only get logout option & when logged out user should get login option.
Please help me regarding this concept.

Comment: Are you using session or cookie for storing status of successful login?

Comment: You aren't giving us enough information. Is this data being retrieved from a cookie or database? Why don't you try showing us an example of your PHP code so we can try to determine how you can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create SESSION variable (with email or any unique attribute) and set it when user LogsIn.

```
eg: session_start();
    $_SESSION['email'] = useremail;
```

and check in every page if session varible is set or not.

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
     //then show login button
}
else{
    //show logout button
}
```

Comment: <?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {
        echo '<li><a href="login.php">LOGIN</a></li>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<li><a href="logout.php">LOGOUT</a></li>';
    }
?>